Blazor Server App 8 and Antiforgery Token
I am trying to use an EditForm in an application with authentication and authorization working correctly. When I tried to submit an EditForm, I get this error:

A valid antiforgery token was not provided with the request. Add an antiforgery token, or disable antiforgery validation for this endpoint.

I have done the following in the Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryFieldname";
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
});
// . . . 
// . . . 
app.UseAntiforgery();

In my EditForm on a Blazor component page, I have:
<EditForm method="post" Model="Membership" OnValidSubmit="AddMembership" FormName="create" Enhance>
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary class="text-danger" />
 

When I looked at the page source, this is what the form looked like:
<form data-enhance="" method="post" action="/memberships/create">
<input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="create" />
<input type="hidden" name="AntiforgeryFieldname" value="CfDJ8KPOziIR...

I am not sure what I did wrong. Before implementing authentication and authorization, the EditForm worked correctly.
I expected this to work based on the Microsoft documentation.

I tried some other EditForm razor pages in the same application. Some worked correctly while others did not with the same error: A valid antiforgery token was not provided with the request. Add an antiforgery token, or disable antiforgery validation for this endpoint.
